# Puppeteer tab crashes only on youtube.com (Aw, Snap! STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to get a screenshot from search results from Youtube. Unfortunately I cannot get the code to work on this page. Any other page (also other pages from youtube work). I also have the same issue when I use 'https://www.youtube.com' as url. This is the code I'm using.

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, devtools: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent(
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
    );
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });

    await page.goto("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=isoleren", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle2", // 
    });

    await page.screenshot({ path: "./screenshot.png" });
```

This is what the browser is telling me. Translated it says:

> 'Something went wrong while viewing the page. Error code 11. More info. Reload'

[image]

Any other link: https://www.youtube.com/@gElement does work. See the result of the screenshot():
[image]

I tried:

- Headless vs not headless
- `waitUntil: load`
- `timeout 0`, which means indefinitely. But its not a timeout issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/10033) so for your code to work you have to reduce your puppeteer version to `^18.2.1` - *version that I've tried that works*

package.json

```js
 "puppeteer": "^18.2.1",
```

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, devtools: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36" );
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });

    async function youtube(search = 'isoleren') {

        let url = `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${search}`;

        await page.waitForSelector(`body`);
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 5000 });        
        await page.screenshot({path: 'youtube.png'})
        await browser.close();

    }

    await youtube();

})().catch(err => console.error(err)). finally(() => browser ?. close());
```

**update**: the bug seems to have been resolved in the new version of puppeteer.

```js
 "puppeteer": "^20.0.0",
```