# Puppeteer youtube tab crashes

Tags: youtube, puppeteer

I am learning Pupputeer, I want to scrap video link of a youtube page (https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=data+science) all the websites are working fine but the YouTube link crash the Chromium browser and link is not opening

I am using Express JS and puppeteer

```js
const express = require("express");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get("/scrapVideo", async (req, res) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.youtube.com");
  await page.screenshot({ path: "youtube.png" });
  await browser.close();
  res.send("working");
});

app.listen(3300);
```

[Webpage error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgsRZ.png)

This is the error this is only happening for YouTube.

Comment: Do you have any reason for not using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint?

Comment: My search quires are dynamic and my web scrapping are depends on different platform that includes youtube too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason that Puppeteer breaks when going to a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76054650/what-is-the-reason-that-puppeteer-breaks-when-going-to-a-url)

Comment: @idchi This is due to chromium browser bug downgrade your puppeteer version to 18.0.0 and it works

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution on puppeteer official git hug. This is due to chromium browser bug downgrade your puppeteer version to 18.0.0 and it works

Comment: If it's a dupe of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76054650/what-is-the-reason-that-puppeteer-breaks-when-going-to-a-url) I would just accept the dupe suggestion rather than posting a less thorough answer of your own. Thanks.